# Unit testing - implementing equals only to facilitate testing

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, equals

Here are my requirements for unit testing:

1. I would like to unit test my production classes
2. I would like to separate test code and production code apart such that I can release production code only

This seems like reasonable requirements. However, a problem always arises when I need to use methods such as `assertEquals` on objects as these requires that the `equals` method is overridden. The `equals` method would have to be implemented in production classes **but is actually only used for testing.** This becomes even worse when good coding practices dictates that if `equals` is overridden, then should `hashCode` also be implemented resulting in even more unused production code that clutters the production classes.

Here is a simple example with a `User` model (IntelliJ autoimplemented `equals` and `hashCode`)

```
public class User
{
    public long id;
    public long companyId;
    public String name;
    public String email;
    public long version;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o)
    {
        if(this == o) return true;
        if(o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        User user = (User) o;
        if(companyId != user.companyId) return false;
        if(id != user.id) return false;
        if(version != user.version) return false;
        if(!email.equals(user.email)) return false;
        if(!name.equals(user.name)) return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        int result = (int) (id ^ (id >>> 32));
        result = 31 * result + (int) (companyId ^ (companyId >>> 32));
        result = 31 * result + name.hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + email.hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + (int) (version ^ (version >>> 32));
        return result;
    }
}
```

As it can be seen, `equals` and `hashCode` takes up a lot of space and clutters the class.

One solution to the problem could be to create a class, `UserTester`, which could have an `assertUserEquals` method that could be used instead of eg. JUnit's `assertEquals`.

Another solution could be to create a `UserComparator`. However, it does not seem like JUnit have any `assertEquals` that takes a `Comparator`.

What is best practices on this point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Uniutils](http://www.unitils.org/summary.html) has a perfect reflection equals method you can use for unit testing. This way your production code remains clear from all this test stuff.

```
public class User { 

    private long id; 
    private String first; 
    private String last; 

    public User(long id, String first, String last) { 
        this.id = id; 
        this.first = first; 
        this.last = last; 
    } 
}
```

Later in test:

```
User user1 = new User(1, "John", "Doe"); 
User user2 = new User(1, "John", "Doe"); 
assertReflectionEquals(user1, user2);
```

If you're using Mockito it has it's own means to do the same thing:

```
Mockito.verify(userDeleter).delete(Mockito.refEq(user));
```

Comment: Just checked their documentation. It seems you should use `assertReflectionEquals` instead of `assertEquals`. It seems that th is the solution to my problem.

Comment: Ehh - Just found a small problem which I haven't presented in my question. What about using frameworks such as [mockito](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/) for mocking? When using methods such as `verify(userDeleter).delete(user)`, it also uses `equals` for testing the arguments. Do you know any solution to that problem?

Comment: Mockito.verify(userDeleter).delete(Mockito.refEq(user)); should help

Comment: What else can I say: Thank you! I am going to use both Uniutils and refEq.

Comment: Hmm. `refEq(...)` is only doing a shallow check. This needs to be in the back of your mind when using it.

Answer (score 1):

I see two different things:

1. Sometimes it's not desirable to override hashcode&equals. It can change behavior of your program and it can hurt your performance, see [Java Overriding hashCode() method has any Performance issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18180899/java-overriding-hashcode-method-has-any-performance-issue/)
2. If there is no customer requirement to override hashcode&equals, like it's value object, you would not do that. Your should provide such code which exactly meets customer criteria, not more. Your test should deal with original implementation in default object.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most efficient but one possible way is to compare fields using reflection.

```
public class Foo {

    int x;

    Foo(int in){
    x = in;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        Foo o1 = new Foo(1),o2= new Foo(1);
        boolean allMatch = true;
        Class<?> c = Class.forName("Foo");
        Field[] fields =  c.getDeclaredFields();

        for(Field f: fields){
            allMatch &= f.get(o1)==f.get(o2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems that Jk1's answer is simply a neatly packaged version of your idea. Is it really that slow?

Comment: Well reflection does have its overheads, but that depends on how and when you are using it. I think using it during test phase should not be an issue, but then again it really depends on how many reflective calls you make. Also, its better to use an existing library but knowing the implementation can help you customize your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AssertJ and its [Recursive comparison](https://assertj.github.io/doc/#assertj-core-recursive-comparison) functionality

```
// assertion succeeds as the data of both objects are the same.
assertThat(actualSherlock)
                .usingRecursiveComparison()
                .isEqualTo(expectedSherlock);
```

Thanks to this library, you can check actual object equality with expected objects without any "test only" equals() and hashcode() overridings.

And reserve equals() overrides for real business use cases.